# How to set name to localhost in fedora15?

Tags: linux, fedora, hostname, domain

I want to set name to my localhost.for example I want **mysite.com** instead of **localhost/mysite** how to do that?

I have searched but couldn't get a solution for Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find and change the following line in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Change it to

```
127.0.0.1       localhost    mysite.com
```

This is client side. Your webserver may need be configured for name based vhosts.